# How do I get devise_async working with Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber

I've followed the instructions for [devise_async](https://github.com/mhfs/devise-async) as per the README and I'm rolling Devise 2.1.2 and delayed_job. In my cucumber tests, I no longer receive the confirmation email as part of the sign-up process. Is there something I should be doing as part of testing? I already set delayed job to skip the actual delay for testing by setting the following in my test environment.

```
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false
```

But even with this set to true, it still fails, albeit more slowly. If I remove the devise_async gem and the relevant lines, everything bursts back into life.

Thanks,
Graeme

Comment: I am struggling to get devise_async working with Cucumber as well. We are using sidekiq, not delayed_job, so your solutions don't apply to me. I have set the cleaner strategy to truncation, but it still fails. Anyone know how to make these play well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new version of devise-async triggers the emails after the record has been committed to the database.  With RSpec, each test is wrapped in a transaction by default. Does Cucumber do the same?  In that case you'll need to turn those test transactions off.

Here's what I use for RSpec:
http://www.denniskuczynski.com/2012/06/22/changing-individual-test-configuration-based-on-passed-in-options.html

Comment: Hi Dennis. Switching to truncation for my DB cleaning strategy fixed the failing tests. Great stuff! I'm now struggling with using transactions for most tests and truncation for selected tests, but I'll save that for a different question. Many thanks,

Comment: Dennis, I couldn't get it to switch strategies using you gist.  I had to change the if statement to "if example.metadata[:with_transaction_callbacks]" from example.options.  Using rspec 2.12.0

Comment: @Dennis Kuczynski you changed something on your blog and link is broken, please copy some more details to the answer, google cached version http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:endxdMrzntoJ:www.denniskuczynski.com/2012/06/22/changing-individual-test-configuration-based-on-passed-in-options.html+http://denniskuczynski.com/2012/06/22/changing-individual-test-configuration-based-on-passed-in-options.html&cd=1&hl=pl&ct=clnk

Comment: The link above as well as the Google cache link are both broken. :-(

Answer (score 2):

you can turn off transactions in cucumber env

see how to use:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Browsers-and-Transactions

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the Delayed::Worker.new.work_off approach ?
Not sure it works for Devise async, but it worked for me previously for checking emails.

Using this step

```
Given /^Jobs are being dispatched$/ do
  Delayed::Worker.new.work_off 
end
```

And running this step before testing emails ?

Answer (score 1):

In case you use devise-async with sidekiq, as some commenters here ask, the solution is to have tests run the workers inline:

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
```

See https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing