# devise-async & sidekiq - RSpec integration spec fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara, sidekiq

I have the following integration tests written for my application's Devise based authentication:

```
# password_resets_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe "PasswordResets" do
  it "emails user when requesting password reset" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    reset_email # or else we'll have the confirmation email in the last assertion
    visit new_user_session_path
    click_link "password"
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    click_button "Send"
    current_path.should eq(new_user_session_path)
    page.should have_content "Will receive"
    last_email.to.should include(user.email)
  end

  it "doesn't email invalid user when requesting password reset" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    reset_email # or else we'll have the confirmation email in the last assertion
    visit new_user_session_path
    click_link "password"
    fill_in "Email", with: 'nobody@example.com'
    click_button "Send"
    current_path.should eq(user_password_path)
    page.should have_content "correct"
    last_email.should be_nil
  end
end
```

and:

```
# registers_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe "Registers" do
  it "should inform the user to confirm account" do
    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
    visit new_user_registration_path
    fill_in "Username", with: user.username
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    fill_in "Confirm password", with: user.password
    click_button "Send"
    current_path.should eq(root_path)
    page.should have_content "You have been sent"
    last_email.to.should include(user.email)
  end
end
```

I am using Sidekiq for background jobs and `last_email` and `reset_email` come from the following module:

```
module MailerMacros
  def last_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  end

  def reset_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
  end
end
```

All three of these specs work fine when deactivating devise-async on the User model. When I switch it on, the password reset specs run OK but the register one complains about last_email being nil and I don't understand why. Is the confirmation mail sent out somehow differently compared to the password reset ones?

Note that I have the `require 'sidekiq/testing/inline'` line in my spec_helper.rb file so that the email sending is done instantaneously and `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` is set for my test environment so that no actual email sending is taking place.

Comment: how did you deactivate devise-async on the User model?

Comment: Hehe, I had to dig up the source code because I didn't remember. Here you go: In the user model `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :async` - this is async on, if you remove :async it's off.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the issue with mhfs' [help](https://github.com/mhfs/devise-async/issues/32). The problem was that I had `config.use_transactional_fixtures` set to true in `spec_helper.rb` and because of this users were created in a transaction and the after_commit hook which would send the email was never called. Password resets apparently didn't run inside transactions, that's why they worked.

So I had to switch use_transactional_fixtures off and use [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) to keep my database tidy.

Here's what I had to modify:

Add `gem 'database_cleaner'` to my `Gemfile`.

Obviously modify `spec_helper.rb`:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Add the following to `spec_helper.rb`:

```
config.before(:each) do
  with_transaction_callbacks = example.metadata[:with_transaction_callbacks]
  if with_transaction_callbacks
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  else
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

And lastly redo my block in `registers_spec.rb` to read:

```
describe "Registers" do
  it "should inform the user to confirm account", with_transaction_callbacks: true do
    [ --- 8< snip --- ]
  end
end
```

The magic happens in the second line.

PS. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406248/how-do-i-get-devise-async-working-with-cucumber/13465089#13465089) Stack Overflow topic as well as [the article](http://www.denniskuczynski.com/2012/06/22/changing-individual-test-configuration-based-on-passed-in-options.html) linked from within it also helped.